# Add a header to a UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating what I thought would be a pretty straight forward scene with text based content. I want the format to be a heading followed by a paragraph of text followed by another heading and so on.

Currently I'm using the interface builder and creating a label, then a UITextView, then another label then another UITextView and so on. Is there a better way as this seems a bit long winded.

Thanks

Shell

Comment: have you tried using `UITableView`? I believe it would work well in your case (each `UITableViewCell` containing a `UILabel` and an `UITextView`).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try with the UITableView with as many as of Sections .

USe `titleForHeaderInSection` for heading && `UItextField` in the Cell.

```
    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return 1 ;
    }

    -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return YourNEed;

    }

    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       // return header_Name accordind to the Sections
switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"1st Label";
           // ...........

    }
```